# How to cancel the root but not the expression inside it?

Tags: cancel, root

I wanted to cancel the root of an expression like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\[\cancel{\sqrt{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}}\]
\end{document}
```

I'm using the [`cancel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package but it draws a line over the entire expression and I wanted it only over the root to cancel with the 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With some guessing for the correct value:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

\[
\cancel{\vphantom{\sqrt{(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e)^{\cancel{2}}}}\hspace{1.5em}}
\hspace{-1.5em}\sqrt{(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e)^{\cancel{2}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this really necessary? By the way, the equality

[image]

is generally ***false***. You need the absolute value and your careless cancellation might give wrong ideas to your students.

A possibly better syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\newcommand{\cancelroot}[1]{%
  \sbox0{$\displaystyle\sqrt{\vphantom{#1}}$}%
  \cancel{\phantom{\usebox0}\hspace{0.5em}}\hspace{\dimexpr-\wd0-0.5em}%
  \sqrt{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\cancelroot{(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e)^{\cancel{2}}}+
\cancelroot{\Bigl(\frac{a}{2}+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\Bigr)^{\cancel{2}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution!!
And thank you for your advice usually I'm the one giving it :D

Comment: A better solution which does not require guessing the amount of negative space (`\hspace{-1.5em}`) would be to create a temporary length: `\newlength{\rooted}\settowidth{\rooted}{\ensuremath{(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e)}}` and then use it in `\hspace` with or without minus sign.

Comment: @JakubNarębski The idea is that the cancellation bar should only cover the radical, not the whole expression, so the amount of space only depends on the height of the material, not on its horizontal size.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen radicals "canceled" like this, but it could be correct given the context, which we don't know. If it's known that the expression under the radical is nonnegative, for example.

Comment: @RichardSullivan Indeed, I wrote “Is this really necessary?” and considered the case that the final expression could be negative: “You need the absolute value and your careless cancellation might give wrong ideas to your students.”

Comment: @egreg I'm not using this without context but you can always cancel if you have $\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2$.

Comment: @Concept7 Yes, but here the square is *under the square root*, not the other way around. Anyway, I don't see how useful is to show the cancellation marks: they're useful on the blackboard just as graphic devices; not on a book: they should be supplied by the students when taking notes. We don't want to make them believe the marks are *necessary*. I have a nice anecdote about the cancellation marks: a poor student got reprimanded because she traced the marks from top left to bottom right, instead of bottom left to top right *as the book does*.

Comment: As I said, I'm not using it without context and I'm not using it in a book.

Answer (score 5):

Some ideas

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
test
\[\cancel{\sqrt{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}}\]
versus
\[\left((a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e)^{\cancel{2}}\right)^{\cancel{\frac12}}\]
or
\[\sqrt[\cancel{2}]{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}\]
or
\[\rlap{$\cancel{\quad\vphantom{\sqrt{()^2}}}$}\sqrt{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}\]
or
\[\cancel{\sqrt{\vphantom{()^2}}}\overline{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}\]
or
\[\rlap{\line(1,1){18}}{\sqrt{\left(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+e\right)^{\cancel{2}}}}\]

\end{document}
```